# Unable to put more than one statement in Axios promise handler Vue Js

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I am using Vue Js within my Laravel project where I use it to make a POST call.
It works fine however when handling the promise I am having the following issues:

```
      axios.post('/customer/update',this.customer)
      .then(response =>(
      //this.customer = response.data.customer //if this line is uncommented, the scripts falls over
      this.error.text = response.data.message
      )).then(response =>(
        this.error.show = true
      )).then(response =>(
        this.error.class = true
      )).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      })
    }
```

I am having to chain several .then()'s together to handle each singular statement within it. Ideally, I would like to do this:

```
      axios.post('/customer/update',this.customer)
      .then(response =>(
      this.customer = response.data.customer
      this.error.text = response.data.message
      this.error.show = true
      this.error.class = true
      )).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      })
    }
```

Any ideas at all, because I am not sure whats wrong with the above at all. It should work but it doesn't.

I get the error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'this'
```

which points to my created tag

```
    created(){
    this.greeting;
    console.log(this.customer)
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess you have typo, using parenthesis instead of curly brackets, should be like below

```js
 axios.post('/customer/update',this.customer)
    .then(response => {
        this.customer = response.data.customer
        this.error.text = response.data.message
        this.error.show = true
        this.error.class = true
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```